# What are the real benefits of using Nose for tests?

Tags: python, bash, testing, nose

Is there anything special with using Nose for tests? From what I have heard the reason most people use Nose is..

- because it gives you a report
- because it shows you the time it took for the tests

How is that any better than using simple Bash like below?

tests.py:

```
assert test1()
assert test2()
assert test3()
print("No errors")
```

runtests:

```
#!/bin/sh
(time python tests.py) > log
return $?
```

Comment: Why do people keep downvoting legit questions? Maybe the admins themselves should read the rules since this question is not asking for a recommendation or anything. It's a very specific question. Or is there a rule that only code questions are allowed on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The benefit of using a standard tool is that you are more likely to find third-party tools which build on top of the tool.  So for just running a test, it doesn't matter what you use, but as soon as you start having many components in a Jenkins rig, having multiple different tools with different output formats and conventions makes it a real problem to maintain and develop monitoring and reporting.

For shell scripts (which I imagine is part of the question because you used the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag and wrote your script in `sh`), it's not like Nose is "the standard", and if you have multiple tools in different languages, it might not be possible to standardize on a single tool / framework / convention (TAP for Perl, Nose for Python, JUnit or whatever for Java ...)

One benefit which you didn't mention is that the framework takes care of a lot of the footwork for you.  A single file with tests could be managed (with some pain) by hand, but once we start talking dozens of files with hundreds or thousands of test cases, you want a decent platform for managing those and let you focus on the actual testing instead of reinventing the wheels that the framework puts there for you to use.